# How to add APA style references in ioslides using rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, ioslides

I'm preparing a thesis presentation using ioslides but I'm not get a clue how to add citations. Though [this](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html) link is very informative but it did not say anything about references.

Answer (score 1):

Try an .Rmd file (not  .Rpres, it's an older method), and then Knit in RStudio

```
---
title: "My presentation"
output: ioslides_presentation
bibliography: C:/Users/Dieter/Documents/bibtex/menne.bib
---


## R Markdown

This is a nice paper (@Ghoos1993)
```

Comment: Good to know. Kindly accept the answer on Stack Overflow

Comment: Believe me, I tried earlier too but it is saying my score is less than 15 so I cannot. Sad.